# how can i pop two elements from a stack and then push in stack them back as sum of values?

Tags: haskell, state-monad

```
import Control.Monad.State

type Stack = [Integer]

pop :: State Stack Integer
pop = state $ \(x:xs) -> (x, xs)

push :: Integer -> State Stack ()
push x = state $ \xs -> ((), (x:xs))

main :: IO()
main = print $ runState `enter code here` [1,2,3,4]
```

> using "pop >>= (\s1 -> pop >>= (\s2 -> push `enter code here`)"
>   what should i write here?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: That definition of `pop` terrifies me; its a deeply hidden partial function. I know it wouldn't be any better `fail`ing in `Identity` for a stack underflow, but it would be less terrifying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler can [figure out the type to fill in a blank](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Typed_holes). If I add a hole `_` to the code

```
add = pop >>= \s1 -> pop >>= \s2 -> push _
```

The compiler tells me it should have the type `Integer`.

```
   Found hole `_' with type: Integer
```

What `Integer` could you put there that would be the sum of the values popped off the stack?

Comment: Why do you think `s1` and `s2` aren't `Integer`s?

Comment: How can i get integer value from the type State in this place?

Comment: `pop` is a `State Stack Integer`. When you `>>=` (pronounced bind) it to a function `\x -> ...` the `x` is an `Integer`. The `...` needs to be a `State Stack a` for some type `a`.

Comment: Thank you!! yes, of course s1 and s2 are integer. i'm just stupid :\

Answer (score 0):

You mean this?

```
popAndSum :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int]
popAndSum elem list = fst xs ++ [sum']
        where
            xs = splitAt ((length list) - elem) list
            sum' = foldl (+) 0 $ snd xs
```

`popAndSum 2 [1,2,3,4,5]` = `[1,2,3,9]`

`popAndSum 3 [1,2,3,4,5]` = `[1,2,12]`